# SpringBoot : possible to have dynmamic values/variables from application.properties into resources

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, properties, maven-resources-plugin

For a SpringBoot app :

I have resources in `src/main/resources` : it can be JSON, XML... doesn't matter

Some resources are dynamic, for example :

```
  {
     "url": "${propA.url}"
  }
```

This `propA.url` is defined in `application.properties` :

```
propA.url=http://localhost
```

Is it possible when building the project to finally having the real value after `mvn package` :

```
  {
     "url": "http://localhost"
  }
```

After compilation, it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

The [properties-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/properties-maven-plugin) can do this. In *pom.xml*:

```
        ...
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>initialize</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <files>
                            <file>src/main/resources/application.properties</file>
                        </files>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        ...
```

Then the [maven-resources-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/) will by default replace, for example, *src/main/resources/app.json* file if put like this:

```
{
    "url": "@propA.url@"
}
```

Executing:

```
mvn package && less -FX target/classes/app.json
```

Will give you (if using the application.properties you mention above):

```
{
    "url": "http://localhost"
}
```